# What exactly does an adjective stem + そう mean?

Tags: conjugations, adjectives

The other day I posted a picture of some food on Facebook, and I noticed that all of my Japanese friends were saying 「おいしそう」. I made a good guess to what it meant, but I wasn't certain what exactly they were saying. I've seen this stem+そう with other i-adjectives too, such as 楽しそう, but none of this is covered in any of my Japanese books.

What exactly is this? Is it slang? Can it be used with na-adjectives or nouns too? If so how? Thanks! :)

Comment: this is the same grammatical pattern, albeit for verbs, explained here http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/607/what-is-the-difference-between-plain-form-of-verb-and-root-of-verb  

And i'm surprised it isn't in any of your japanese books, cause it is basic pattern that would usually show up book 1 or 2 of beginners japanese as it is on the JLPT.

Comment: Related exceptional case: [“Seemingly cute” - かわいい + 〜そう](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3126/542)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[See [this question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/607/what-is-the-difference-between-plain-form-of-verb-and-root-of-verb), which deals with the same pattern when used with verbs.  I'll adapt my answer from that question to answer yours.]

-そう after the stem of a adjective means "looking/sounding as if ___." おいしそう means "it looks as if it will be delicious." It is similar to constructions like おいしいみたい or おいしいよう, but -そう emphasizes evidence of the senses rather than general "seeming."

Contrast it with おいしいそう, which means "it is said to be delicious."

You can use -そう with verbs, adjectives, and some na-adjectives, but not with nouns.  Here are some na-adjective examples:

- 駄目そう (looks like it's no good)
- 丈夫そう (sturdy-looking)
- 元気そう (peppy-looking)
- 大変そう (Sounds rough!)

You can also use the -そう phrase itself as a na-adjective:

- おいしそうなケーキ (a delicious-looking cake)

Comment: Does adjective stem + そう always become na-adjective? What about verb stem + そう --> 壊れそうなバス?

Comment: @Lukman Yes, it's all the same pattern, so they would all become na-adjectives.

Comment: Btw is おいしいみたい  rude? Like "it looks as if it is tasty but it isn't" ?

Answer (score 4):

It seems ...

For instance

- おいしそう = it seems delicious
- 行けそう = it seems I will be able to go

It is not slang, it is grammatically correct.

Detailed explanation:
http://www.guidetojapanese.org/similar.html#part4