# 食べたそうだ vs. 食べそうだ, 静かだそうだ vs. 静かそうだ

Tags: grammar, formal-nouns, morphology

I saw this as a comment on this question, [Why does そう in 「美味しいそう」 not mean "seem" the way I think it should?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1994/why-does-%E3%81%9D%E3%81%86-in-)「美味しいそう」-not-mean-seem-the-way-i-think-it-should,

and would love to understand the differences.

I am sure I will mangle the translation, so forgive me.

> 食べたそうだ  Looks like he ate it.
>
> 食べそうだ  Looks like he will eat it.
>
> 静かだそうだ I heard that it's quiet.
>
> 静かそうだ  Seems quiet.

If anyone would be kind enough to explain the differences in meaning and usage, I would greatly appreciate it. I didn't learn how to embed the quoted question, so sorry again for that.

Comment: 「食べたそうだ」can be '①Looks like he ate it/I heard he ate it (食べた+そうだ=食べたらしい、食べたようだ)' and '②Seems like he wants to eat it (食べたそう+だ=食べたいようだ)'. Ah but the intonation is different.

Answer (score 7):

**The first そう** comes after 終止形 of verbs and adjectives. All 終止形 forms, negatives, passives, causatives, present and past etc are possible.

This means "I hear(d)/read that... " (not looks/seems like as assumed in the question).

> 彼は死んだそうだ I heard he died
> あのケーキは美味しいそうだ I hear that cake is declicious
> 彼は嫌われていなかったそうだ They say he wasn't hated.

This そう is often listed as a particle, but it really behaves like a noun, and is almost always followed by copula. It has no 連体形, i.e. 静かだそうな is ungrammatical (unless な is the sentence-ending particle). Also, the following copula is not used in the past tense, i.e. 静かだ(った)そうだった does not exist, but 静かだったそうだ does.

**The second そう** comes after the 連用形 of verbs and the stem of adjectives. 良い(いい) and 無い have irregular forms 良さそう and 無さそう. Negative verb forms ～ない become ～なそう, but ～なさそう is often heard, although it's considered incorrect.

> 濃{こ}そう, 静かそう, 行きたそう, 食べなそう looks dense, seems quiet, looks like *sby* wants to go, looks like *sby* won't eat

The result of this is a na-adjective meaning "looks ..." or "seems ...". For action and state-change verbs, it can also meen "about to ..." or "looks like *sby* will ...".

Being a na-adjective, this form can be used both in the 終止形 and 連体形 forms (and negative forms etc.),

> 美味しそうなケーキ a delicious-looking cake
> このケーキは美味しそうだ this cake looks declicious
>
> 死にそうな人 a person (looking like he's) about to die
> 彼は死にそうだ (he looks like) he's about to die

Comment: How is this different from my answer? Looks like partly rephrasing it in terms of traditional grammar, but not all the way (acknowledging that they are noun or a na-adjective rather than "助動詞")? And by `It has no 連用形, i.e. 静かだそうな`, you mean it has no 連体形？ And for this form, what about in folk tales: `昔、おじいさんとおばあさんがあったそうな。`.

Comment: @sawa Sorry, you still hadn't posted when I started writing my answer. I see there are overlaps, but I also provide some new information, such as そうだった and 良さそう. Is it faux pas to post overlapping information? I already fixed the 連体形. About the そうな, good point. I was never quite sure how to parse that construct in folk tales. I consider that use fossilized, though.

Comment: I see that you started writing before I posted. No problem.

Comment: @dainichi, thank you. what does sby stand for?

Comment: @yadokari Somebody. Not sure if this is the best way, but I use it sometimes when English grammar requires a noun, but it can be dropped in Japanese. I think some dictionaries use it.

Comment: Hmm, didn't know that ～なそう　was a valid form of negative verb + そう (looks like). My textbooks tell me to use 連用形 + そう に/も/じゃ ない (apart from one which still goes for なさそう!)

Answer (score 3):

The `そう` that takes an appositive clause is a formal noun (although in traditional grammar, it is not called so). It has reference to a general situation that one heard from someone else. Or, it may be considered a sentence ending. This happens in **syntax**.

> [寒い]そうだ
>   'What I heard is that it is cold.'
>
> [食べた]そうだ
>   'What I heard is that she ate it.'
>
> [静かだ]そうだ
>   'What I heard is that it is quiet.'
>
> [日本人だ]そうだ
>   'What I heard is that the person is a Japanese.'

The `-そう` that attaches to a verb stem, adjective stem or an adjectival noun (a.k.a. na-adjective, 形容動詞語幹) is an affix that derives a na-adjective that means `just about to`. `likely to`, `it looks like`. This happens in **morphology**.

> [寒そう]だ
>   'It looks cold'
>
> [食べそう]だ
>   'She is just about to eat it.'
>
> [静かそう]だ
>   'It seems to be quiet.'

It does not attach to a noun. In order to express a similar meaning with a noun, you can use `っぽい`.

> 日本人っぽい
>   'The person looks like a Japanese.'

Since that latter `-そう` derives a adjectival noun, it can be used to modify a noun.

> [寒そう]な部屋
>   'a room that looks cold'
>
> [食べそう]なもの
>   'things that she is likely to eat'
>
> [静かそう]な物件
>   'a real estate in a quiet environment'

Comment: can these interpretations be valid for this?
食べそうだ
"She is likely to eat it."
"Looks like she'll eat it."
If they are valid, how can one differentiate the meaning? (
'She is just about to eat it.'is a different meaning than the others)

Comment: @yadokari The difference comes from what temporal instance you are focusing on. In `just about to`-interpretation, it is mentioning that "she is likely to eat it **in the next moment to come**." So it is actually the same.

Comment: @sawa Btw for the first そう (the sentence-ending そう), is "寒いですそうだ" a valid construction? What about "日本人ですそうだ" ?

Comment: @Pacerier They are invalid. In general, subordinate clauses cannot be in polite form.

Comment: @sawa Hey thanks for the reply =) Btw I was wondering does the meaning of the first そう (the sentence-ending そう) extends beyond *physical-hearing*? For example, can 静かだそうだ mean "I read (in a magazine/newspaper) that the place is quiet" ?

Comment: @Pacerier Yes. That is possible. The key is that it is not something that you directly perceived.